# Logistic Regression - Are estimators biased when there's low variance in X?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, estimation, generalized-linear-model

I am studying logistic regressions and I wonder why are estimators biased when the independent variables have low variance (maybe low variance compared to its mean, but anyway).

I simulate the underlying model as a linear function of a single variable `x` and I do not include an error term. `x` is generated from a normal distribution, with mean `mx` and sd `sx`.

`f` is a helper to map the probabilities using a logistic function

I use `mx = 1.0`, and sample `sx` from a uniform distribution from 0 to 1, so I can estimate the model for different values of `sx`.

```
SAMPLE_SIZE = 1000
set.seed(100)

f <- function(v) exp(v) / (1 + exp(v));

sim = function(b0, b1, mx, sx) {
  xs <- rnorm(SAMPLE_SIZE, mean = mx, sd = sx)
  ps <- f(b0 + b1 * xs)
  ys <- rbinom(SAMPLE_SIZE, 1, ps)
  glm(ys ~ xs, family = binomial)
}  


sx <- runif(n = 1000, min = 0.05, max = 1.0)
b0 = 1.5
b0s <- sapply(sx, function(v) {
  sim(b0 = b0, b1 = 1.0, mx = 1.0, sx = v)$coefficients[[1]]
})
```

And then I plot the error between the estimated `b0` coefficient and the real one, for different values of `sx`:

```
plot(sx, b0s - b0)
```

What I get is that the error gets smaller the greater `sx` is.

From common linear regressions, we know that the estimators get more precise the larger the variance in the independent variables. But that does not say anything about the biases.

How to interpret this result? Are the estimators really biased in logistic regressions? What's missing here? Is there any problem related to numerical estimates here?

[image: Estimation error vs. standard deviation in X]

Comment: How does this address bias? You plot at the end doesn't seem to indicate any bias.

Comment: Your plot *does* demonstrate variance, however...

Comment: Hummm it really does not demonstrate bias but does demonstrate variance... Thanks for the answer. @Dason

Answer (score 2):

Note that the apparent 'bias' disappears when you make `mx=0`, as in:

```
library(txtplot)
f <- function(v) exp(v) / (1 + exp(v));

sim = function(b0, b1, mx, sx, SAMPLE_SIZE=1000) {
  xs <- rnorm(SAMPLE_SIZE, mean = mx, sd = sx)
  ps <- f(b0 + b1 * xs)
  ys <- rbinom(SAMPLE_SIZE, 1, ps)
  glm(ys ~ xs, family = binomial)
}

b0 <- 1.5
b1 <- 1.0
mx <- 1
sx <- seq(from=0.05,to=1.0,by=0.005)
set.seed(100)
b0s <- sapply(sx, function(v) {
  sim(b0 = b0, b1 = b1, mx = mx, sx = v)$coefficients[[1]]
})
#' And then I plot the error between the estimated b0 coefficient and the real one, for different values of sx:
txtplot::txtplot(sx,b0s-b0,width=90)

#'    +---------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+---+
#'  4 +     *                                                                               +
#'    |                                                                                     |
#'    |                                                                                     |
#'  3 +   *                                                                                 +
#'    |                                                                                     |
#'    |                                                                                     |
#'  2 +                                                                                     +
#'    |                                                                                     |
#'    |   *                                                                                 |
#'    |       *        **                                                                   |
#'  1 +      *  *             *                                                             +
#'    |     *   *   *     ***             *   *                                             |
#'    |           ** *    * *            *  *       *   * **     *                          |
#'  0 +          * *    *    ********* *************** ************** ***** *************   +
#'    |       * *             **** *  **    * **** *  **    ** *  ** **** ** *    *   **    |
#'    |    *   *   *  *  *   *  *   * * *          *                                        |
#'    |      *    * ****    *                                                               |
#' -1 +     * ** *     *                                                                    +
#'    |    *                                                                                |
#'    +---------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+---+
#'                   0.2              0.4             0.6             0.8               1

# and again, with mx=0
mx <- 0
set.seed(100)
b0s <- sapply(sx, function(v) {
  sim(b0 = b0, b1 = b1, mx = mx, sx = v)$coefficients[[1]]
})
#' And then I plot the error between the estimated b0 coefficient and the real one, for different values of sx:
txtplot::txtplot(sx,b0s-b0,width=90)
#'      +---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---+
#'      |                                                       *                           |
#'      |                                                                                   |
#'  0.2 +                                            *                                      +
#'      |                                 *                 *                               |
#'      |           *       **             * *    *   *              *               *      |
#'      |      *      *                      *    *          *    *                 *       |
#'  0.1 +        *       *   *  *   *    *                           *       *   *  ***     +
#'      |   ***        * *     *     *     **    * **                             *   *     |
#'      |       *   **      **          *     **          *    ***     ***      *           |
#'      |     *   *        *  ** *     *       **     *      **          *    *             |
#'    0 +   *        *  * *    *  ** *   ***    *   *   * **        *        *              +
#'      |       *  *  *               ***        *      **  *      *      * *  *   *        |
#'      |        *   * **  *     *   **  *   *      *  *    * *   **  ***             * *   |
#'      |      *   *                *         *   *  *     *        * * * *   * ***         |
#' -0.1 +                  *  *    *   *                      **            *     *    *    +
#'      |    *   **      **                 *      *    *           *      *   *       **   |
#'      |                                                                 **       *        |
#'      |                                      *                  *             *   *       |
#' -0.2 +                         *                                                         +
#'      +---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---+
#'                     0.2             0.4             0.6             0.8              1
```

Think about it this way: your independent variable $x$ has mean 1 and standard deviation `sx`. When `sx` is very small, $x$ is almost indistinguishable from the constant 1 intercept 'variable', so a logistic regression 'has a hard time' disambiguating the effect of $x$. This is much easier when the variation in $x$ (and thus the resultant variation in the odds of the dependent variable) is larger.